# Getting the anonymous function of an object in QtScript for later calling

Tags: qt, qtscript

How can i get the anonymous function placed into an object/variable and store it for later calling?

Lets say i have this JS:

```
callMeLater = function(){var foobar = "baz!";}
```

How can i store `callMeLater` from my `QScriptValue object`?
`object.toString()`, so that i could feed that to `engine.evaluate` later, sadly doesn't work.
I could simply fill `callMeLater` with a string from inside JS, but that doesn't feel right.